# Dynamically Rendering a React Component in React 0.12

Tags: reactjs

[I asked this question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518629/dynamically-rendering-a-react-component), but with React 0.12 and the JSX changes it brought, I'm now seeking another way to implement this feature.

Here's the code that works in React 0.11:

```
return React.createClass({
    render: function() {

      var Tag = React.DOM[this.props.element];

      return (
        <Tag className='text'>
          {this.props.value}
        </Tag>
      );
    }
});
```

I'm making a component that renders different DOM elements based on the prop passed in called "element".  this.props.element will be a value such as "p", "h1" or "h2" etc.  While this technically works, I'm seeing a warning message in the console:

```
Warning: Do not pass React.DOM.p to JSX or createFactory. Use the string "p" instead.
Warning: Do not pass React.DOM.h2 to JSX or createFactory. Use the string "h2" instead.
```

Need some direction to help interpreting that warning and I can't find good documentation for how to do something like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Super simple answer to this (+1 for React 0.12 making things simpler!) but all that needed to be done is remove the React.DOM[] part of the variable definition, passing the string literal:

```
return React.createClass({
    render: function() {

      var Tag = this.props.element;

      return (
        <Tag className='text'>
          {this.props.value}
        </Tag>
      );
    }
});
```

Works beautifully; without any console warnings!

Comment: As an extra plus, you could also pass a custom component, e,g, MyComponent instead of "p" or "h1".  Terminology wise, an element in react is the result of `<Something />` (which compiles to React.createElement(Something)`), 'component' or 'type' or something more specific to the use case might be a clearer prop name.

Comment: !IMPORTANT! Tag name must be capitalized in order for it to work.