# Render a React component based on its name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Context: I am developing a widget-based webapp, (like the defunct iGoogle, where users can choose which widgets they want to display). Each widget is a React component.

Simplified example:
Here are 2 different widgets

```
var HelloWidget = React.createClass({
    render: function() { return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>; }
});

var HiWidget = React.createClass({
    render: function() {  return <div>Hi {this.props.name}</div>; }
});
```

As a user, I have chosen the HiWidget and my name is "dude" so when the system gets my preferences from the persistence layer it looks like this:

```
var dataFromDb = {
    type: 'HiWidget',
    name: 'dude'
};
```

How can I render a React component when I have its name in a string var ?

I tried this, based on [Dynamically Rendering a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518629/dynamically-rendering-a-react-component) :

```
React.render(
  <dataFromDb.type name={dataFromDb.name} />,
  document.getElementById('try2')
);
```

It used to work with React 0.11, but not anymore.

And I would like to avoid having a giant switch statement:

```
switch (dataFromDb.type) {
    case 'HiWidget':
        var component = <HiWidget name={dataFromDb.name} />;
        break;
    case 'HelloWidget':
        var component = <HelloWidget name={dataFromDb.name} />;
        break;
}
React.render(
  component,
  document.getElementById('try3')
);
```

JSFiddle with all this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/61xdfjk5/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use an object as a lookup for the component type and keep the details of rendering it in one place:

```
var components = {
  'HiWidget': HiWidget,
  'HelloWidget': HelloWidget
}

var Component = components[dataFromObj.type]
React.render(
  <Component name={dataFromObj.name}/>,
  document.getElementById('try3')
)
```

Answer (score 3):

JSX is a superset of JavaScript, so you can always use native JavaScript syntax inside of JSX. For example, if classes of your components are available in global space (`window`), you can do the following:

```
React.render(
  React.createElement(window[dataFromDb.type], {name: dataFromDb.name}),
  document.getElementById('try2')
);
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpx6o0eg/1/).

Comment: I don't understand why `window[...]` is necessary here! The variable dataFromDb is in scope since `dataFromDb.name` works fine but if I remove the `window[...]` it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @al8anp You need `window[...]` because that way you get reference to class, `dataFromDb.name` is just a string representation of class name. `React.createElement(...)` expects class as first argument