# React generate components with dynamic tags babel es6

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I would like to be able to change the tag of a React component parent node like so

```
React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        const tagName = this.props.tagName;
        const domTag = tagName ? React.DOM[tagName] : React.DOM.div;
        return <domTag />
    }
})
```

drawing reference from this question and answer

[Dynamically Rendering a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518629/dynamically-rendering-a-react-component)

But when I use the above method, my react component tag type is domTag...

Any ideas? I'm webpack and babel to compile the code.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is ...

you just pass a string, and not the DOM function, ie.

```
const TagName = 'input';
return <TagName />
```