# React Native Dynamically Inject Component at Runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to dynamically inject a component at runtime with react native. I receive data from an API endpoint, which I then set in state. There are currently three possibilities -> EventModal, ArticleModal, NewsModal. I import all three. A simplified example of what I'm trying to do is below....

```
render() {
    let Page = { component: this.state.currentModal + "Modal" };
    return (
        <Page.component />
    );
}
```

That is similar to [Dynamically Rendering a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518629/dynamically-rendering-a-react-component)

But unfortunately doesn't seem to working (both examples in and out of brackets) as I receive the error "expected a component class, got EventModal". Similarly I tried with the object syntax

```
 render() {
    let Page = this.state.currentModal + "Modal";
    return (
        <Page />
    );
}
```

However same result. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are adding the 'Modal' which turns the variable into a string so is not a component. Also, React Native does not treat any variable as a Component unless it has an uppercase at the beginning.

So try something like this (you will have to add the others as well):

```
    import EventModal = require('./EventModal');

render(){
    let Component = null;

    switch(this.state.currentModal){

       case: 'EventModal':
       Component = EventModal;
    break;

    }

    return <Component/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import/require EventModal. So in that case it's better not to use string and use the reference

```
var EventModal = require('../components/EventModal');
render() {
   let Page = EventModal;
   return (
    <Page />
   );
 }
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified better. The modal is based on an outside JSON source / API source, it come sin as a string. I import all possibilities but don't know which to use until the render. Heres what it looks like...

    render() {
        let Page = state.dataModal;
        return (
            <Page />
       );
    }

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Still you would need to require/import all possible modal types. Is that something you've done in that file?
React can parse strings and references just the same, but references are more "minifiable" (even native apps can benefit from it).

Comment: I have imported all three and what I hard code them in as I typically would the app runs correctly