# How to render React component taken from an array of objects and pass props to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an array of objects, one of the properties of each object is a JSX element that I want to render based on an index that I keep as a state in the parent component. I also need to pass props to these components, so I thought I could do something like `<MyArray[index].myJsx foo="bar" />` But this seems not to be a valid syntax (due to the index part, I guess). How could I accoplish that? I don't think `Array.map()` fits my use case, since I want to show these components one at a time

Comment: did you try Reac.createElement ?

Comment: Tried `const Context = MyArray[index].myJsx` and then inside a return a `<Context foo="bar" />`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically Rendering a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518629/dynamically-rendering-a-react-component)

Comment: @LeoLima thanks, this does exactly what I need! The aswers linked by superhawk610 didn't fit my problem because the array caused problems with JSX syntax